# COMPILE_TIME_ASSERTs all fail referencing dlib as shared library

Tags: java, c++, cmake, java-native-interface, dlib

I'm trying to write a JNI wrapper for dlib so that I can obtain face descriptors in Java.
I've written the jni code to do it, but I can't seem to `make` it (on MacOS X).
My JNI doesn't create any compile errors, but a ton of the COMPILE_TIME_ASSERTS fail when `make`-ing it.

What am I doing wrong and how can I successfully accomplish this?

**CmakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(dlib-jni)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
# add_subdirectory(../dlib dlib_build)
include_directories(src)

find_package(dlib REQUIRED) #possibly supporting components!
# include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS "Using dlib-${dlib_VERSION}")

find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
message (STATUS "JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message (STATUS "JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH =${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH}")
message (STATUS "JNI_LIBRARIES=${JNI_LIBRARIES}")
message (STATUS "JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=${JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY}")
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(dlib_jni SHARED src/dlib-jni.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dlib_jni dlib::dlib opencv_core opencv_highgui)
```

**cmake Command**:

```
cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/opt/opencv/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake  ../
```

**cmake Output**:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using dlib-19.15.99
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found suitable version "3.3.1", minimum required is "3") 
-- Found JNI: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjawt.dylib  
-- JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/include;/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin;/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/include
-- JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH =/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/include
-- JNI_LIBRARIES=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjawt.dylib;/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
-- JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev):
  Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

   dlib_jni

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/me/gitrepos/dlib-jni/build
```

**make command**:

```
make && make install
```

**First Error (there are many)**:

```
/usr/local/include/dlib/array2d/../geometry/../image_processing/../image_transforms/image_pyramid.h:940:13: error: static_assert failed "Failed assertion"
            COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT( pixel_traits<in_pixel_type>::has_alpha == false );
```

Comment: It might be a stupid question, but is there another OpenCV installed under `/usr/local/`? I'm asking because in the command that you issued you have `/usr/local/opt/opencv/share/OpenCV/`. Also, minor detail, issuing `cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/opt/opencv/share/OpenCV/` should be enough, as the `_DIR` is required for finding a package CMake file.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've just discovered the problem, and it was a problem with my c++ code  I'm going to post an answer now.

Comment: No worries. I don't have that environment running here, so I thought by the way the question was phrased that it was a setup problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT`s are there to ensure that your code that uses dlib is actually correct.

As it happens, mine wasn't.

In my case I had created a dlib cv_image from an OpenCV Mat, like so:

```
dlib::cv_image<rgb_pixel_apha> img(image);
```

And then attempted to detect faces like so:

```
std::vector<dlib::matrix<rgb_pixel>> faces; 
for (auto face : detector(img)) 
...
```

The keen-eyed developer will notice that they're templated differently. One is a `rgb_pixel_alpha`, and the other is an `rgb_pixel`.

The COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT checking for the alpha channel picked up on this. I just didn't understand the error properly.